# how to get reverse time in android from US time

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.currenttime;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Functions {

    private static long converTimeStringINToMillis1(String time) {

        long milliseconds = 0;

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            // 25/06/2014 8:41:26

            Date date;

            date = sdf.parse(time);
            milliseconds = date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            milliseconds = 0;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return milliseconds;
    }

    public static String setLastSeenTime1(String time) {

        long milliseconds = Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis()
                - converTimeStringINToMillis1(time));
        String lastSeen = "";

        int seconds = (int) milliseconds / 1000;
        if (seconds < 60)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf(seconds) + "sec ago";
        else if (seconds > 60 && seconds < 3600)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf((int) seconds / 60) + " min ago";
        else if (seconds > 3600 && seconds < 86400)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf((int) seconds / 3600) + " hours ago";
        else if (seconds > 86400 && seconds < 172800)
            lastSeen = " Yesterday";
        else if (seconds > 172800 && seconds < 2592000)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf((int) (seconds / (24 * 3600)))
                    + " days ago";
        else if (seconds > 2592000)
            lastSeen = String.valueOf((int) (seconds / (30 * 24 * 3600)))
                    + " months ago";

        return lastSeen;

    }

}
```

i have display reverse time i calling this function Using this of android code:

```
btn_retry.setText(Functions.setLastSeenTime1("09/10/2014 8:41:26 AM"))
```

But Problem is i am getting server time which is located in Us i have to display according to Local time ZOne so that i can see eject reveres time please Suggest me how i will do where am doing wrong please help .

Comment: it seems you are setting Coordinated Universal Time as Timezone...so can you elaborate which TimeZone you are looking for.

Comment: UTC i want to COnvert

Comment: Convert Both time Utc and means Device time and Server time on the basis of that we have to find difference that we have to display in text view

Comment: hello @Toppers please give me Solution i have tried But not getting Solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: 
This should work, just replace this within your utility class, you just have to pass the time and the serverTimeZone.

```
public static String setLastSeenTime1(String time, TimeZone serverTimeZone) throws  ParseException {

   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
   sdf.setTimeZone(serverTimeZone);

   SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

   return sdf2.format(sdf.parse(time));

}
```

Comment: Updated the answer - added some code. The difference can be negative. You just need to "correct" the server time by the difference to get local time.

Comment: Please add in My code duede coz unable to Ingrate this code

Comment: Updated my answer - now integrated solution into your code

Answer (score 1):

in converTimeStringINToMillis1 use like this

```
     Date date = new Date();
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

     // Use UTC time zone to format the date in
     df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

     System.out.println("Date and time in UTC: " + df.format(date));
```

Comment: i am able to do this but how i will conver Device time in UTC basically i have to find

Comment: This will return the UTC time only..... Can you elaborate little with or can you give a small example.

Answer (score 1):

## Joda-Time

Rather than roll-your-own, just use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Joda-Time works in Android.

The example code below uses Joda-Time 2.4.

Joda-Time uses the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard string formats as defaults for both parsing and generating string output. Seen here in the [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), Interval, and Period strings.

Parse the input string. Note how we specify a time zone and a [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) (to parse the "AM" value in English).

```
String input = "09/10/2014 8:41:26 AM";
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" ).withZoneUTC().withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );
DateTime then = formatterInput.parseDateTime( input );
```

Get the current moment. Use that moment to build an [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) from then to now.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
Interval interval = new Interval( then , now );
```

Convert interval to a [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), a span of time defined as a number of days, hours, and such.

```
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
```

Generate a textual representation of the Period. This example accesses a default period formatter. Instead, you may build your own custom formatter via the [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) class.

```
PeriodFormatter formatterOutput = PeriodFormat.wordBased( Locale.US );
String output = formatterOutput.print( period );
```

For fun, show a different language. Arbitrarily choosing Québec style.

```
String outputQuébécois = PeriodFormat.wordBased( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).print( period );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "then: " + then );
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "interval: " + interval );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
System.out.println( "outputQuébécois: " + outputQuébécois );
```

When run.

```
input: 09/10/2014 8:41:26 AM
then: 2014-09-10T08:41:26.000Z
now: 2014-10-09T20:44:23.470Z
interval: 2014-09-10T08:41:26.000Z/2014-10-09T20:44:23.470Z
period: P4W1DT12H2M57.470S
output: 4 weeks, 1 day, 12 hours, 2 minutes, 57 seconds and 470 milliseconds
outputQuébécois: 4 semaines, 1 jour, 12 heures, 2 minutes, 57 secondes et 470 millisecondes
```