# PeriodFormatter not showing days

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, periodformatter

I am using a PeriodFormatter to return a string showing the time until an event.  The code below keeps creating strings like 1146 hours 39 minutes instead of x days y hours z minutes.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Nathan

```
   PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                .printZeroNever()
                .appendDays()
                .appendSuffix( "d " )
                .appendHours()
                .appendSuffix( "h " )
                .appendMinutes()
                .appendSuffix( "m " )
                .toFormatter();
        return formatter.print( duration.toPeriod() );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you convert [**Duration**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) to [**Period**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) with method [**Duratoin::toPeriod**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDuration.html#toPeriod())
This is described in Joda-time documentation:

> public Period toPeriod() Converts this duration to a Period instance
>   using the standard period type and the ISO chronology. **Only precise
>   fields in the period type will be used. Thus, only the hour, minute,
>   second and millisecond fields on the period will be used**. The year,
>   month, week and day fields will not be populated.

Period insance cann't be calculated properly without start date (or end date), because some days can be *24h* or *23h* (due to DST)

You shoud use method [**Duration::toPeriodFrom**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDuration.html#toPeriodFrom(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)) method instead
E.g.

```
Duration duration = new Duration(date1, date2);  
// ...  
formatter.print( duration.toPeriodFrom(date1));
```

Comment: Good answer. In contrast, calling `Interval::toPeriod` does render weeks, days, and such because the interval is anchored on the timeline by DateTime values. See [an answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26287848/642706) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

As Ilya said by default the toPeriod method will only populate **hour, minute, second and millisecond fields**.
But you can actually normalize that back using `normalizedStandard` so that

```
String periodFormat(Duration d) {
    return PERIOD_FORMATTER.print(d.toPeriod().normalizedStandard());
}

static final PeriodFormatter PERIOD_FORMATTER = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
  .appendWeeks().appendSuffix("w")
  .appendSeparator("_")
  .printZeroRarelyLast()

  .appendDays().appendSuffix("d")
  .appendSeparator("_")
  .printZeroRarelyLast()

  .appendHours().appendSuffix("h")
  .appendSeparator("_")
  .printZeroRarelyLast()

  .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("m")
  .appendSeparator("_")
  .printZeroRarelyLast()

  .toFormatter();
```

Will pass

```
  @Test
  public void periodFormatTest {
    assertThat(periodFormat(Duration.standardMinutes(5))).isEqualTo("5m");
    assertThat(periodFormat(Duration.standardMinutes(60))).isEqualTo("1h");
    assertThat(periodFormat(Duration.standardDays(1))).isEqualTo("1d");
    assertThat(periodFormat(Duration.standardDays(2))).isEqualTo("2d");
    assertThat(periodFormat(Duration.standardHours(47))).isEqualTo("1d_23h");

  }:
```