# Different behavior of PeriodFormatter on different devices (JodaTime)

Tags: android, jodatime, duration, period, periodformatter

I'm implementing count down timer for the android app using JodaTime.
Depending of devices the output is different.

```
       DateTime openingDateTime = new DateTime(2018, DateTimeConstants.JUNE, 14, 21, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Moscow"));
        DateTime nowDateTime = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Moscow"));
        long difference = openingDateTime.getMillis() - nowDateTime.getMillis();
(...)
onTick(difference);

(...)

    PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroAlways()
            .appendDays().appendSuffix(" day", " days")
            .appendSeparator(" ")
            .appendHours()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .appendMinutes()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .appendSeconds()
            .toFormatter();
(...)    

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Duration duration = new Duration(millisUntilFinished);
            Period period = duration.toPeriod(PeriodType.dayTime());
            tvCounter.setText(periodFormatter.print(period));
        }
```

On the one device output is correct: **491 days 4:39:18**
on the other is wrong: **0 days 11788:49:11**.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have different versions of Joda-Time on your devices. What so ever, I can reproduce only your second (wrong) example, and the [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDuration.html#toPeriod-org.joda.time.PeriodType-) says: "Only precise fields in the period type will be used. At most these are hours, minutes, seconds and millis "

Comment: Why do you not simply use `Period p = new Period(nowDateTime, openingDateTime, PeriodType.dayTime());` instead of this lossy millisecond-conversion?

Comment: @MenoHochschild Versions of Joda-Time are the same. I don't know why but Joda must use inner android implementation of some kind of information connected to my solution.

Comment: @MenoHochschild  You're right, in this case I have to forget about default long millisUntilFinished parameter (it comes from CountDownTimer android SDK solution) and use simple Period(DateTime, DateTime, PerdiodType)

Comment: Hm, I cannot see how Joda-Time uses inner android implemenations... but maybe something about the default zone of the device where you get expected output is strange. Can you debug it?

Comment: @MenoHochschild You're right, changing default zone affects on the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to your comments, **I can now reproduce your problem**. Just add following static initializer to your test class (at first place) to simulate the device where you observe your expected output:

```
static {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
}
```

According to the spec (see also the [accepted answer on this SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26293614/2491410)), the conversion `duration.toPeriod(periodType)` should only use so-called precise duration fields, that is hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds but not days.

### My analysis of source code of Joda-Time (v2.9.6):

The internal class [org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/chrono/BasicChronology.java) contains following constant:

```
private static final DurationField cDaysField = new PreciseDurationField(DurationFieldType.days(), 86400000L);
```

So we see that here this duration field is marked as "precise", but: The subclass ZonedChronology wraps it and override the behaviour of method [isPrecise()](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/chrono/ZonedChronology.java#L305):

```
public boolean isPrecise() { 
  return iTimeField ? iField.isPrecise() : iField.isPrecise() && this.iZone.isFixed(); 
}
```

**This shows an extra zone dependency of the precision property of the days()-duration-field, namely precise for fixed zones like UTC and else imprecise.**

I don't know if the analyzed and observed behaviour is a feature or a bug. Let's say, it is dangerous to expect the creation of `Period`-objects by `duration.toPeriod(...)` to be zone-independent. And it is [not documented there](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDuration.html#toPeriod-org.joda.time.PeriodType-) to have a precise days-component if the system zone is fixed.

Unfortunately, the implicit dependency on the default time zone is deeply coded into Joda-Time via its chronology-design. **As workaround, you can use**:

```
Period p = new Period(nowDateTime, openingDateTime, PeriodType.dayTime());
```